# Как запустить бота в webhook mode на aiogram 3.x?

Tags: aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Всем привет!
Запустил бота на удаленном сервере с помощью polling, столкнулся с проблемой ответов от телеграма gateway timeout и решил переделать на вебхуки с проксированием через nginx. В aiogram 2.x была возможность перевести бота в webhook mode с помощью aiogram.utils.executor.start_webhook, подскажите, как это реализовать в новой версии?